# How to debug a js script whose name changes

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'd like to debug a js script whose name changes every time that it's loaded (a timestamp is added at the end of the file, for preventing caching).

For this reason, if I set a breakpoint and then reload the page, the debugger loads the new file and does not stop on the old one.

Is there any tool for any browser (better for IE) to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this reason I'm using `debugger;` function and add to those JS code parts, when I need to stop debugger.

It works good when you have always changing script and not depend on browser type.

```
function someFn() {
   debugger;
   ...
}
```